# Trace Evil-mode commands

Tags: key-bindings, evil, commands

At the moment, I only know one way to determine which Emacs functions are called by any given Evil command (e.g. a sequence of key bindings in the Normal state): read the Evil source code.

Is there a more reliable and efficient way, and if so, what is it? For example, does Evil (or Emacs) have a mechanism that allows the user to tell Emacs:

> "When I enter my next command, show me afterwards which Emacs functions it mapped to."

Comment: How is this different from `F1 k`?

Comment: I.e. Emacs's `describe-key` command? Similar idea, only I'd be grateful for something more Evil-aware. In Evil's Normal state, I might type, for example, `vip` to select the current paragraph. If I type `F1kvip`, the `describe-key` command kicks in after the `v`, and describes only that ("v runs the command evil-visual-char"), which means the succeeding `ip` results in switching to Insert state and inserting the character 'p' at that point in the buffer. This means that I still do not know which command/function `vip` calls, and I also have to undo the accidental insertion :)

Comment: As far as Evil is concerned, `v` is a standalone command, same goes for `ip` in its visual state map (`ip` in normal state map is a different story...).  The behaviour of `F1 k` mirrors this, so nothing unusual going on.

Comment: @wasamasa, good point, thanks. I guess that using `describe-key` to trace the command components piecemeal is probably the best way to go after all. If you post that as an answer, I will accept and upvote it :)

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely happy with this as answer because there are actually ways of tracing the last commands (as opposed to keystrokes) which could be more helpful in special cases, such as `daw`.

Comment: @wasamasa, if you have a better answer in mind, by all means post it. Thanks again!